# Insert data Restful API Phil Sturgeon

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert, restful-authentication

Can anyone show me how to insert data to mysql by using Phil Sturgeon Restful sever?
It's OK when I get data using GET method, but when I tried insert using POST method to insert data it allways echo like this:

```
{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}

<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class Api extends REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->Model("user_model");
    }

    function register_post() {
        $username       = $this->post('username');
        $password       = $this->post('password');
        $firstname      = $this->post('firstname');
        $lastname       = $this->post('lastname');
        $mobile         = $this->post('mobile');
        $sex            = $this->post('sex');
        $avatar         = $this->post('avatar');
        $active         = $this->post('active');
        $device_token   = $this->post('device_token');
        $fbconnected    = $this->post('fbconnected');
        $token          = $this->post('token');

        $register = array(
                'username'      => $username,
                'password'      => MD5('".$password."'),
                'firstname'     => $firstname,
                'lastname'      => $lastname,
                'mobile'        => $mobile,
                'sex'           => $sex,
                'avatar'        => $avatar,
                'active'        => $active,
                'device_token'  => $device_token,
                'fbconnected'   => $fbconnected,
                'token'         => $token
                );
            $this->user_model->register($register);
            //$this->response($register, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your method needs to be called name_get or name_post

Comment: with get method I just call name without _get, but I don't know how to call post method, I can insert data using GET method but I can't do with POST method

Comment: Rename it to _post at the end and it will work

Comment: my method name is "register_post", so my url should like this: "http://localhost/restserver/index.php/api/api/register_post/format/json", is this?

Comment: no - just /api/register/format/json but when you POST to that URL the register_post method is used

Comment: oh, thank you. But when I call method like you, It response to me like this: {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}. (I just try to run that method, I don't have any input form)

Comment: are you sure there are 2 api folders ? /api/register would seem muuch more normal, Couild you post your code

Comment: I'm sure, because I have an api folder and an api.php file

Comment: I'm a new member so I can't post my function :(.

Comment: function register_post() {...} this is my method

Comment: edit your question and paste the code ?

Comment: I did that. If you don't mind, can you show me how to make a PUT request? :)

Comment: OMG, I fixed my problem, ^^. Just because I didn't send any data to my POST method. I tried to use Postman Chrom Extention. Finally It worked! Thank you very much!